# How Many Licks Does It Take To Get To The Center Of A Tootsie Pop?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

### How Many Licks Does It Take To Get To The Center Of A Tootsie Pop?

Given a constant **$P$** representing the diameter of the sphere of a tootsie pop, and a constant **$p$** representing the diameter of the sphere of the chewy tootsie ball inside, one can determine the volume of lolli material **$V_l$**.

> If one represented the length of a licker's tongue as **$T$**, how many licks does it take to get to the center of a tootsie pop?

[image]

Comment: Assuming that this is not a real math problem or something, maybe lateral thinking should be there?

Comment: @ZaniXu I believe that "Enigmatic" pretty much covers all.

Comment: We can't say how may licks it take, because surface area of tongue is not same for all. It seems like some scientific experiment needed for prove it. http://tootsie.com/howmanylick-experiments

Comment: One.  Then I give up and crunch the damn thing.

Comment: Is this a dry tongue, so only frictional removal of hard material happens, or is it a nice wet tongue, in which case contact time for dissolving is more important than contact area

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Taking

> pairs of lollipops as directions for flag semaphore,

we get

> **ONE WITH A LONG ENOUGH TONGUE**.

Comment: Can someone do the maths? I need to know how many miles long it would be...